# Javascript: Iterating over array with non-consecutive keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, iterator

I need to iterate over an array for which the keys are non-consecutive:

```
var messages = new Array();
messages[0] = "This is the first message";
messages[3] = "This is another message";
```

Obviously using the index of a for loop will not work as it depends on the keys being sequential:

```
for (var i=0 ; i<messages.length ; i++) {
    alert(messages[i]); // Will only alert the first message, as i is never equal to 3
}
```

What is the canonical way of dealing with this, seeing as [the for-each syntax is not intended for iterating over values in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065358/javascript-object-property-not-in-scope)? Thanks.

Comment: How did you end up with such an array in the first place? Instead of looking for some hacks to iterate over it why don't you tackle the problem at its root => which is the way you obtain this array.

Comment: Have you considered using an Object instead? `{ "0": "this is the first message", "3": "this is another message"}`

Comment: *Will only alert the first message, as i is never equal to 3* this is not correct. `messages.length` will be `4`.

Comment: The array represents object, not simple string literals as in the example. The array keys are the database primary keys. Having the primary keys as another property of the object leads to all kinds of complications as I usually know which object to access by ID, so having the ID as the array key is very convenient. That is, other than this one issue.

Comment: @Yoshi: You are right, the loop must be throwing an exception and quitting when it hits the invalid array key. Either way, the approach won't work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be to use an object, not an array.  Just be sure to check `hasOwnProperty` to make sure you don't pick up stray things which may have been added to the prototype.

```
var messages = { };
messages[0] = "This is the first message";
messages[3] = "This is another message";

for (var i in messages) {
    if (messages.hasOwnProperty(i))
        alert(messages[i]); 
}
```

---

Or, the more modern way would be to use `Object.keys`

```
Object.keys(messages).forEach(prop => {
    alert(messages[prop]);
});
```

Be sure to transpile that code with Babel if you plan on running it in older browsers like IE.

Comment: ... squeezing in a `hasOwnProperty()` check would increase the awesomeness of this answer.

Comment: Why not call `hasOwnProperty` on the messages directly?
`if( messages.hasOwnProperty( i ) ) { alert( messages( i ) ); }`

Comment: @meouw - it's just an extra-safe, though probably unnecessary precaution to protect you from the slim possibility that messages has defined a property or function named `hasOwnProperty` - `{}.hasOwnProperty.call` ensures that you'll always get the one on object.prototype

Comment: OK - I think it clouds the issue a bit though. You're answer is not as clear as it could be because you are addressing not only the OP's question but another issue as well.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question, it still confuses me how some of the stack community decide to start asking irrelevant questions or telling your your wrong but fail to give you good reasoning.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(var i in messages)
{
    console.log(messages[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see that console.log() is quite a powerful tool!

Answer (score 3):

You could ignore the `undefined` properties...

```
for (var i=0 ; i<messages.length ; i++) {
    if(messages[i] !== undefined)
        alert(messages[i]);
}
```

Or use `forEach`, which will ignore <s>`undefined`</s> undeclared properties...

```
messages.forEach(function(v,i) {
    alert(v);
});
```

Comment: ohhh - +1 for forEach - didn't know that ignored undefined properties.

Comment: `forEach` is not implemented in IE < 9 though.

Comment: @Tim - true...I guess I just (usually) have the luxury of ignoring that fact :)

Comment: To be clear, `forEach` does not ignore elements with a value of `undefined`.  If you say `messages[n] = undefined` and then call `messages.forEach()`, the element at `n` will be processed.  Instead, `forEach` skips indexes for which no element exists in the Array.  The same logic can be used by testing `if (i in messages)`.

Comment: @gilly3: You're right. Undeclared would have been a better word.

Answer (score 2):

Simple! if the array has regular gaps between the indices do this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i += gap) {
    alert(messages[i]); // Will only alert the messages at the regular interval/gap 
}
```

Comment: Though this would work for a gap that would be constant, the OP states that the keys are non-consecutive, which is not the same as having a constant gap.

Comment: Not the same but includes this case, then it is the code for it, which I clearly stated at the very beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` jQuery method to do this.

```
$.each(messages, function(index, val){
    alert(val); 
});
```

From jQuery docs

`each()`

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate
>   over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a
>   length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated
>   by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via
>   their named properties.

Comment: Is "jQuery" *really* the best solution for simple enumeration?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, and you find that `$.each(messages, function(index, val){` is simpler than `for (var i in messages) {`? I guess we have different definitions of *simplicity*.

Comment: I think using the fundamental language construct "`for`" is both  **cleaner** and **simpler** than using `jQuery.each`.

Comment: Because `jQuery` gives the `index` and `value` seperated as callback arguments, you don't have to maintain variables. If performance is the concern I would definitely go with classic JavaScript way using `for` or `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array and give it values at `0` and `3`, `undefined` values are created at `1` and `2`. try this:

```
$.each(messages, function(i,val) { 
  if (val) {
    alert(val);
  } 
});
```

Comment: Is "jQuery" *really* the best solution for simple enumeration?

Comment: That depends on what you consider "best". For someone that is learning javascript and has access to jquery, using the jquery each can avoid other common issues found when using a for loop without knowing how they work.

Comment: If all you look at is "fastest", it would be best to never use a javascript library, right?

Comment: @Matt - the real answer here is that when you create an array with values at `0` and `3`, the indexes at `1` and `2` are populated and iterated through. His original code will alert all messages. How you iterate over them doesn't matter.

Comment: When you create an array with values at 0 and 3, there are no elements at 1 or 2.  It's not that the elements at 1 and 2 contain a value of `undefined`.  There simply are no elements at indexes 1 and 2.  Try this in a JavaScript console: `var a = [1]; a[3] = 1; console.log(1 in a);`

Answer (score 0):

For a use case such with the assumptions:

`array.length >== 1`
(i.e: an array with meaningful data in it already)

Where you are interested in the data from `array[1], array[15], array[45]` etc

You can do something similar to:

```
var array = ["you","will","become","strong","with","the","codes","padawan"];
var values = [1,5,7];


for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var cypher = values[i];
    console.log(array[cypher]);
}
//will, the, padawan
```

Or perhaps something more meaningful such as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var cypher = values[i];
    aService.aFn.(array[cypher],cb);
}
//calls aService.aFn separately for each value array[1] , array[5] , array[7] passed as args
```