# What are the JavaScript constructs `{}` and `call()`?

Tags: javascript, syntax

In response to a previous question, I received [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9066531/343302):

```
for (var i in someArray) {
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(someArray, i))
        alert(someArray[i]); 
}
```

My questions are:

1. Where can I read about the {} construct? I cannot find it in the jQuery docs, and it is impossible to google for.
2. Where can I read about the call() function. [Searching the jQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=call&go=) does not turn up anything seemingly related.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing in the code seems to be jQuery related in fact.

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it was jQuery or Javascript, and I could not find the resources to know if it was jQuery specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `{}` is *one* way to declare an empty object. It is called object literal syntax and you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals).
2. The `call()` method is a JavaScript method (not jQuery). Again, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Basically, `call()` allows you to change the value of `this` inside the function you're calling `call()` on. It is related to [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply);

   ```
   var array = new Array;

   function foo() {
       alert(this === array);
   };

   foo(); // false;
   foo.call(array); // true
   ```

Looking at the code in particular, we're looping over an array and using the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) method to check the value (`i`) exists **on** the `someArray` array (as opposed to being in the prototype chain of `someArray`.

As for why we're using `{}.hasOwnProperty` as opposed to `someArray.hasOwnProperty`, I *guess* that the user might be protecting *against* `hasOwnProperty` being declared on `someArray` (by using an empty object). If he hadn't done this, then the following could have been possible;

```
var someArray = [];
someArray.hasOwnProperty = function () { 
    return true; // always return true... muahahaha.
}
```

Or even;

```
var someArray = [];
someArray.hasOwnProperty = 4; // now hasOwnProperty isn't even a function. Calling someArray.hasOwnProperty() will result in an error.
```

Comment: The hasOwnProperty check is there to protect against undefined objects in the array, as not all the array elements are sequential. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. {} is an object literal (pure javascript) nothing to do with jQuery

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

1. call method is again pure javascript, not jQuery specific

http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/call.html

So Google on 'javascript object literal', or 'javascript call method'.. couple of examples linked above.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing jQuery and JavaScript.

`{}` is a JavaScript construct and is an empty object.

[`call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is also part of JavaScript